# Add region around SVG path for mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js

Is there a way to add a region over a line path in an svg-generated graph?

I want a user to be able to hover **near** , not just over, a line on a line chart and have things happen after the mouseover.

Currently, with the code I have, you have to mouseover the actual line. But I want to set a region around the line.

(Adding padding to the path doesn't seem to work)

Comment: just create an invisible rectangle (region) so when you hover over that rect your mouseover event fires

Comment: Am I appending the rect to the path or the path to the rect?

Comment: just append the rect to whatever you're appending the path to but append the path to it first so the rect gets created on top of the path

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks. This seems to work. Now I just have to figure out how to size the rect appropriately.

Answer (score 9):

My approach would be to draw a second `path` over the first, which uses the same data and line function, but is transparent and with a larger `stroke-width`.

Then attach the `mouseover` and `mouseout` listeners to the fatter line.

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/henbox/u0vz96qe/1/

Note that for demo purposes, the fatter line is not fully transparent. To make it invisible, just change

```
.fatpath {
    ...
    opacity:0.1;
}
```

to be `opacity:0;`

Comment: This solution can work. Is there any pure CSS solution? Thanks